# Pandas check if duplicate value from one column has value in another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The logic that I'm looking for is that, if in x column there is a duplicate value, indicate if that value in any row has a specific string in another column. This might work with a binary function.

For instance:

| X | Y | Z |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Incorrect | A |
| 1 | Correct | G |
| 2 | Incorrect | A |
| 2 | Incorrect | G |

In the table above I want to create another column `'Has Correct in Y?'` that has a boolean value: if the duplicate value in X has the string "Correct" in the column Y in any of the rows that it is present in.

The result would be something like this:

| X | Y | Z | Has Correct in Y? |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Incorrect | A | TRUE |
| 1 | Correct | G | TRUE |
| 2 | Incorrect | A | FALSE |
| 2 | Incorrect | G | FALSE |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with

```
df['Corr_Y'] = df['X'].isin(df.loc[df['Y'] == 'Correct','X'])
```

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
df['Has Correct in Y?'] = (df['Y'].eq('Correct')
                           .groupby(df['X'])
                           .transform('any')
                           )
```